# Copy a part of an image in opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to split an image into several sub-images with opencv by identifying templates of the original image and then copy the regions where I matched those templates. I'm a TOTAL newbie to opencv! I've identified the sub-images using:

```
result = cv2.matchTemplate(img, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
```

After some cleanup I get a list of tuples called points in which I iterate to show the rectangles. tw and th is the template width and height respectively.

```
for pt in points:
    re = cv2.rectangle(img, pt, (pt[0] + tw, pt[1] + th), 0, 2)
    print('%s, %s' % (str(pt[0]), str(pt[1])))
    count+=1
```

What I would like to accomplish is to save the octagons (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/region01.png) into separated files.

How can I do this? I've read something about contours but I'm not sure how to use it. Ideally I would like to contour the octagon.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If template matching is working for you, stick to it. For instance, I considered the following template:

[image]

Then, we can pre-process the input in order to make it a binary one and discard small components. After this step, the template matching is performed. Then it is a matter of filtering the matches by means of discarding close ones (I've used a dummy method for that, so if there are too many matches you could see it taking some time). After we decide which points are far apart (and thus identify different hexagons), we can do minor adjusts to them in the following manner:

- Sort by y-coordinate;
- If two adjacent items start at a y-coordinate that is too close, then set them both to the same y-coord.

Now you can sort this point list in an appropriate order such that the crops are done in raster order. The cropping part is easily achieved using slicing provided by `numpy`.

```
import sys
import cv2
import numpy

outbasename = 'hexagon_%02d.png'

img = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1])
template = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(sys.argv[2]), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
theight, twidth = template.shape[:2]

# Binarize the input based on the saturation and value.
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
saturation = hsv[:,:,1]
value = hsv[:,:,2]
value[saturation > 35] = 255
value = cv2.threshold(value, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# Pad the image.
value = cv2.copyMakeBorder(255 - value, 3, 3, 3, 3, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=0)

# Discard small components.
img_clean = numpy.zeros(value.shape, dtype=numpy.uint8)
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(value, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 500:
        cv2.drawContours(img_clean, contours, i, 255, 2)


def closest_pt(a, pt):
    if not len(a):
        return (float('inf'), float('inf'))
    d = a - pt
    return a[numpy.argmin((d * d).sum(1))]

match = cv2.matchTemplate(img_clean, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)

# Filter matches.
threshold = 0.8
dist_threshold = twidth / 1.5
loc = numpy.where(match > threshold)
ptlist = numpy.zeros((len(loc[0]), 2), dtype=int)
count = 0
print "%d matches" % len(loc[0])
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cpt = closest_pt(ptlist[:count], pt)
    dist = ((cpt[0] - pt[0]) ** 2 + (cpt[1] - pt[1]) ** 2) ** 0.5
    if dist > dist_threshold:
        ptlist[count] = pt
        count += 1

# Adjust points (could do for the x coords too).
ptlist = ptlist[:count]
view = ptlist.ravel().view([('x', int), ('y', int)])
view.sort(order=['y', 'x'])
for i in xrange(1, ptlist.shape[0]):
    prev, curr = ptlist[i - 1], ptlist[i]
    if abs(curr[1] - prev[1]) < 5:
        y = min(curr[1], prev[1])
        curr[1], prev[1] = y, y

# Crop in raster order.
view.sort(order=['y', 'x'])
for i, pt in enumerate(ptlist, start=1):
    cv2.imwrite(outbasename % i,
            img[pt[1]-2:pt[1]+theight-2, pt[0]-2:pt[0]+twidth-2])
    print 'Wrote %s' % (outbasename % i)
```

If you want only the contours of the hexagons, then crop on `img_clean` instead of `img` (but then it is pointless to sort the hexagons in raster order).

Here is a representation of the different regions that would be cut for your two examples without modifying the code above:

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I got the following error: line 23, in <module>
    _, l[i] = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(l[i], cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY),
error: /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/OpenCV-2.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:3205: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cvtColor. I honestly don't have a clue on how to fix it... Do you have any idea on what's the problem?

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp that is caused because either the template or the input  has a single channel already. If the image of your template has a single channel and is binary already, you can add a `break` statement right after `_, l[i] = cv2.threshold(...)`. This will process only the input then. In this case you might as well rewrite that piece to eliminate the `for` loop.

Comment: It was a dumb mistake, I was using a wrong filename. I fixed and ran it with a breakpoint on the line 50th (after the first loop). I suppose that ptlist should have something but is empty. If I setup the threshold to 0.95 it seems to work only for the second columns of octagons. When I to run it with this image https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/blob/master/test01.jpeg it doesn't produce any output with threshold = 0.99, and it seems to hang with threshold = 0.95. I will upload the code to a git repo later on and post the link.

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp the fact that it seems to hang might be because it found too many matches, and part of the algorithm is `O(n^2)`. From the initial question it seemed like template matching was working for your problem, and you had a good template. It doesn't seem to be the case, is it ?

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp retry with the updated code. Threshold at 0.99 is certainly too optimistic, except if you have a very good template and it is very consistent across the images you might have.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! The code looks very interesting indeed. Could you please tell me which python / opencv version are you using? I'm really confused, here are the results after running the code: https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/tree/master/out-multisearch04, and here is the code: https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/blob/master/multimatch04.py. Do you have any idea on why is working for you and not for me? I'm using python 2.7 and opencv 2.4.3. I tried to identify with rectangles the zones matched but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp maybe you used an older version of the code to get those results ? But I've noticed the previous template was weak, it could match irrelevant areas easily, the new template (basically a negated version of the earlier one) is better for the task. I've also done other minor modifications in the code that improves the speed. With this new template, you can use a wider range of thresholds for filtering the match that it still works (by default it is set to 0.8),

Comment: I'm deeply sorry to bug you out much with this issue and I really appreciate all your support and help so far. Could you please tell me the OS and version you are using (also of python and opencv)? Here is the img_clean image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/mmgp%20-%20capture.png. I found interesting that top and bottom lines of each octagon is quite weak, perhaps that is why is not working for me? I copy your code and added some imshow popups just to check each stage. Code: https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/blob/master/multimatch05.py

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp the left image is certainly not the resulting `img_clean`, it is more likely to be the `value` image after `findContours` has been used. `findContours` modify the input image, and it makes no sense to show it after that. The left image cannot be the `img_clean` one because every contour is draw at a thickness of 2, which is clearly not the case. I cannot access your code, paste it on pastebin.com

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp also, please make sure you are using the template at http://i.stack.imgur.com/JE0qA.png.

Comment: Thank you very much once again! Now it seems to work fine. Could you please tell me how did you transform the original template file (https://dl.dropbox.com/u/239592/search-pattern04.jpeg) into the negated one you created? I will probably need to do this later and if I can somehow reproduce it, it would be very nice.

Comment: @AlbertVonpupp to negate is only a matter of binarizing the template and performing `255 - binarizedimg`. I never used this template you just pointed, by the way. It can be used (after the negation step), but first you need to remove the extra empty area around it, and then reduce the matching threshold to something around `0.7`.

Comment: Thanks!! it works great! I could do it, I just noticed that your results seems more accurate than mine, so the template makes a difference. I noticed that the lines on your template are thicker than in mine, you did this by hand (gimp or similar) or automatically? Many thanks for all the help you both gave me!

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry, I didn't understand from your question on how do you relate matchTemplate and Contours.

Anyway, below is a small technique using contours. It is on the assumption that your other images are also like the one you provided. I am not sure if it works with your other images. But I think it would help to get a startup. Try this yourself and make necessary adjustments and modifications.

What I did :

1 - I needed the edge of octagons . So Thresholded Image using Otsu and apply dilation and erosion (or use any method you like that works well for all your images, `beware of the edges in left edge of image`).

2 - Then found contours (More about contours : http://goo.gl/r0ID0

3 - For each contours, find its convex hull, find its area(A) & perimeter(P)

4 - For a **perfect octagon**, `P*P/A = 13.25 approximately`. I used it here and cut it and saved it.

5 - You can see cropping it also removes some edges of octagon. If you want it, adjust the cropping dimension.

Code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('region01.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh,None,iterations = 2)
thresh = cv2.erode(thresh,None)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
number = 0

for cnt in contours:
    hull = cv2.convexHull(cnt)
    area = cv2.contourArea(hull)
    P = cv2.arcLength(hull,True)

    if ((area != 0) and (13<= P**2/area <= 14)):
        #cv2.drawContours(img,[hull],0,255,3)
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(hull)
        number = number + 1
        roi = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
        cv2.imshow(str(number),roi)
        cv2.imwrite("1"+str(number)+".jpg",roi)

cv2.imshow('img',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Those 6 octagons will be stored as separate files.

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer Abid. I've used this code to match the templates https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/blob/master/multimatch02.py. Your code is awesome and it will help me a lot. I used the matchtemplate approach to match just the octagons, since as you can see contours will match also part of the bottom information (which should be avoided). I just need to get 35 images (coming just from the octagons) at the end. Thanks again for your great help. I will try to adjust my code using contours within matchTemplate.

Comment: I forgot, it's also important that I get the octagons in an ordered way (top to bottom, left to right). I could filter the smalest image in a quick and dirty way. Code: https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/blob/master/contour01.py

Comment: You can find centroids of these octagons using cv2.moments(). Then sort those contours according to their (x,y) coordinates. Hope you can do that. To find moments, read this article : http://goo.gl/tvy9r

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Abid! I will research about that. I'm a total newbie, but I think/hope I will be able to do so.

Comment: sure. you can. It is easy. I was a newbie when I started hearing this contour and other concepts. If I can learn it, you too can. Good luck on your journey.

Comment: The step "... and apply dilation and erosion (or use any method you like that works well ..." is being both too optimistic and not receiving the due credit. The ad-hoc and fragile choice of 2 dilations and 1 erosion is what makes the code return the correct hexagons, did you try, for example, replacing 2 iterations by 1 iteration or 3 iterations ? Did you try removing erosion ? The fact that `findContours` is giving more than one external contour seems to be just an implementation detail, since the contours are all connected.

Comment: You are right about the iterations. I got it by brute force. And I knew it. Seeing this in forward, I already mentioned on top of answer, it is just for a " help to get a startup, may not work in all cases". And I stressed 'fragility' of preprocessing part in point 1 again.(I think you didn't see those description, may be you jumped directly to code. Otherwise, you wouldn't have put that comment).

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I already did the modifications and it seems to works fine. It seems to export all the octagons in order, except the ones that has lines across (shape 21 and 29). Do you have any idea why this happens? I honestly have no clue at all, maybe it has something to do with the contour not working fine with human lines splitting the octagons? Thanks a lot again for all your help! Code is available: https://github.com/vonpupp/opencv-learning/blob/master/contour01.py

Comment: I am sorry, what is shape 21 and 29? Which image you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks for you answer! When you see the test01 image file, there are numbers on the right, which match the count of that file. For instance to easily get to shape 21, check the last closest number on the right (20), and then count the difference (1) from left to right on the next line. So shape 21 is on the fifth row/first column, and shape 29 is on the sixth row/fourth column (up to down, left to right). Interestingly those shapes are 'cutted' by human lines, perhaps that is why they cannot be found by the contours method? If is so,is it still possible to use this method to find the octagons?

Comment: I didn't see that image. I thought your images will contain perfect octagons only. If there are lines crossing, then matchtemplate itself would be better method than contours. And below @mmgp has showed it nicely.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK I believe the approach in your answer can still work if the pre-processing is done in a different manner (just copy & paste the one done in my answer and it should mostly work). The advantage of using template matching in this example is that I can actually remove all the pre-processing (and use only a direct binarization) and lower the matching threshold to something around 0.5 - 0.6, and all (and only) the hexagons will still be matched correctly given the template used -- although none of this was commented in my own answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot both for your great help. Abid, sorry for the misunderstanding, maybe I didn't know how to explain myself properly (English is not my native tongue, and I don't have ANY experience with opencv, this is my first one). If you don't mind I will acknowledge mmgp answer as the right one, nevertheless I will vote up yours aswel. Again, thank you both!

Comment: Yeah, No problem. @mmgp's answer is more appropriate for your question. Actually there was no problem with your question, I just didn't see the second image. Anyway, thanks for the upvote and best wishes on your project. :)

Comment: @mmgp : it may be working. But it will be a "head-ache" to remove the crossing lines and it may cause error at any time (if a different line comes or something else). But your template matching, I think, is simple, and much more robust. `Who want to go for a dirty method when there is a simple clean method is available?` .( I am a little bit lazy person actually. Just want to get the things done as fast as possible).